# curl works in browser and osx cli, but does not work with phpstorm cli

Tags: php, curl, phpstorm

I've got a really odd problem and no idea how to debug it. Maybe some experienced developer can help me. I've the following code:

```
$url = 'https://home.mobile.de/home/ses.html?customerId=471445&json=true&_='.time();
echo $url;
$agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.130 Safari/537.36';

// Initiate curl
$ch = curl_init();
// Activate debugging
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
// Disable SSL verification
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
// Will return the response, if false it print the response
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
// Set browser user agent
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
// Set the url
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
// Execute
$result=curl_exec($ch);
// Closing
curl_close($ch);

$php_object = json_decode($result);
var_dump($php_object);
```

I've put this code into a php file called playground.php. If I open playground.php with Chrome (I am using MAMP as local server) then everything works as expected. Also if I run on the osx command line "php playground.php" it works as expected, but for any reason it does not work if I run it inside the Phpstorm cli as shown below.

[image]

Any idea what could be wrong and how I can debug this issue?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: If you run `which php` on the terminal, do you get a different path from using in your PhpStorm settings? It could be due to different php versions, since PhpStorm is probably running the built-in version. Perhaps you need to enable it in it's php.ini, or something :) EDIT: this might be helpful; https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/configuring-local-php-interpreters.html

Comment: @Ciccio PhpStorm does not have any "built-in" PHPs -- it only uses yours (whatever you configure as PHP Interpreter)

Comment: Right now it rather looks like Firewall/Proxy issue (unable to make outgoing request)...

Comment: P.S. You should also note that you are using different path for your script in actual project and in Run configuration (`/ab/` vs `/autoboerse-dielheim/`)

Comment: @all: Thanks for your response. "which php" returns in any case /usr/bin/php

Comment: @LazyOne sorry, you are right. I couldn't read the screenshot details. With built-in i meant the "https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/php-built-in-web-server.html", I thought it could be possible that uses a different version. But what you say is correct, running different scripts and the request is unable to connect.

Comment: `/usr/bin/php` -- I assume that this is what you have configured as your PHP Interpreter for this project, right? Also -- will your script work if you run it manually from built-in Terminal?

Comment: @LazyOne: Thanks for the hint with the path. There I was just testing something. Actually I am sure that the path is correct as the script works in with Chrome & OSX CLI, but for any reason not with Pphstorm.

Comment: @HH. As you say -- if it works then it works. Just note that IDE complains about missing/invalid file name in that configuration )clearly shown on your screenshot).

Comment: Are both scripts requesting https?

Comment: @LazyOne: Thanks. One issues I have made is to configure the wrong interpreter. I used /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.2/bin/php instead of /usr/bin/php. Now I changed the interpreter to /usr/bin/php, but issue still remains.

Comment: @LazyOne: I overlooked the question "will your script work if you run it manually from built-in Terminal?" Yes. Thats fine. And finally I got it. It was really a firewall issue. Many thanks to all and especially to LacyOne!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to LazyOne I was able to find out that a firewall rule was blocking the outgoing request. Many thanks!